# Google Maps API draw predefined route NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function displayRoute() {

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(28.694004, 77.110291);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(28.72082, 77.107241);

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();// also, constructor can get "DirectionsRendererOptions" object
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // map should be already initialized.

    var request = {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
   </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayRoute">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Why is this not working???**

I am simply trying to NOT have the user input the two coordinates, I want to predefine those and just have a map with a route drawn on it.  Ideally I just want a line, I don't want directions or anything.

**Bottom line: I simply want to highlight the road between two given points.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create an instance of the DirectionsService:
       `var map;`
       `var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();`
   Also the onload should be `onload="displayRoute()"`

Comment: This works on my side.  Did you change onload="displayRoute" to onload="displayRoute()"?